# A required class was missing while executing org.mortbay.jetty:maven-jetty-plugin:6.1.26:run: org/mortbay/util/Attributes

Tags: java, maven, activeweb

I have just trying to run ActiveWeb example https://github.com/javalite/activeweb-bootstrap

Cloning code:

```
D:\Users\Dims\Design\!Pure>git clone https://github.com/javalite/activeweb-bootstrap.git
Cloning into 'activeweb-bootstrap'...
remote: Counting objects: 54, done.
remote: Total 54 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (54/54), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
```

Changing directory:

```
D:\Users\Dims\Design\!Pure>cd activeweb-bootstrap
```

Running maven goal:

```
D:\Users\Dims\Design\!Pure\activeweb-bootstrap>mvn jetty:run
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for org.javalite:activeweb-bootstrap:war:1.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 31, column 21
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.javalite:activejdbc-instrumentation is missing. @ line 66, column 21
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building ActiveWeb Example using Bootstrap 1.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> maven-jetty-plugin:6.1.26:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ activeweb-bootstrap >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ activeweb-bootstrap ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1251 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\Users\Dims\Design\!Pure\activeweb-bootstrap\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ activeweb-bootstrap ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1251, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 5 source files to D:\Users\Dims\Design\!Pure\activeweb-bootstrap\target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> activejdbc-instrumentation:1.4.9:instrument (default) > process-classes @ activeweb-bootstrap >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ activeweb-bootstrap ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1251 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\Users\Dims\Design\!Pure\activeweb-bootstrap\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ activeweb-bootstrap ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< activejdbc-instrumentation:1.4.9:instrument (default) < process-classes @ activeweb-bootstrap <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- activejdbc-instrumentation:1.4.9:instrument (default) @ activeweb-bootstrap ---
**************************** START INSTRUMENTATION ****************************
Directory: D:\Users\Dims\Design\!Pure\activeweb-bootstrap\target\classes
**************************** END INSTRUMENTATION ****************************
[INFO] Instrumentation: directory D:\Users\Dims\Design\!Pure\activeweb-bootstrap\target\test-classes does not exist, skipping
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ activeweb-bootstrap ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1251 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\Users\Dims\Design\!Pure\activeweb-bootstrap\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ activeweb-bootstrap ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1251, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to D:\Users\Dims\Design\!Pure\activeweb-bootstrap\target\test-classes
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< maven-jetty-plugin:6.1.26:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ activeweb-bootstrap <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jetty-plugin:6.1.26:run (default-cli) @ activeweb-bootstrap ---
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.mortbay.jetty.plugin.Jetty6RunMojo
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mortbay/util/Attributes
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:389)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:259)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:235)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:227)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:389)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:259)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:235)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:227)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:455)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:367)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClassFromSelf(ClassRealm.java:389)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:42)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:259)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:235)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:227)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2658)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2007)
        at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forConstructorOf(InjectionPoint.java:245)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.create(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:99)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createUninitializedBinding(InjectorImpl.java:653)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:863)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:790)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:278)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:210)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:986)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1019)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:982)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1032)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:86)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:55)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:70)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:100)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusLifecycleManager.onProvision(PlexusLifecycleManager.java:133)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:109)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:55)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:68)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:997)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1047)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:993)
        at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:82)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:260)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:252)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:462)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:119)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:582)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mortbay.util.Attributes
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:259)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:235)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:227)
        ... 96 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.388 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-09-11T18:32:28+04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/232M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.mortbay.jetty:maven-jetty-plugin:6.1.26:run (default-cli) on project activeweb-bootstrap: Execution default-cli of goal org.mortbay.jetty:maven-jetty-plugin:6.1.26:r
un failed: A required class was missing while executing org.mortbay.jetty:maven-jetty-plugin:6.1.26:run: org/mortbay/util/Attributes
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.mortbay.jetty:maven-jetty-plugin:6.1.26
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/D:/Users/Dims/Design/!Lib/!m2/repository/org/mortbay/jetty/maven-jetty-plugin/6.1.26/maven-jetty-plugin-6.1.26.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/D:/Users/Dims/Design/!Lib/!m2/repository/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty/6.1.26/jetty-6.1.26.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/D:/Users/Dims/Design/!Lib/!m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/D:/Users/Dims/Design/!Lib/!m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.2/junit-3.8.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/D:/Users/Dims/Design/!Lib/!m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-plugin-tools-api/2.0/maven-plugin-tools-api-2.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/D:/Users/Dims/Design/!Lib/!m2/repository/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty-plus/6.1.26/jetty-plus-6.1.26.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/D:/Users/Dims/Design/!Lib/!m2/repository/geronimo-spec/geronimo-spec-jta/1.0.1B-rc4/geronimo-spec-jta-1.0.1B-rc4.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/D:/Users/Dims/Design/!Lib/!m2/repository/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty-naming/6.1.26/jetty-naming-6.1.26.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/D:/Users/Dims/Design/!Lib/!m2/repository/javax/mail/mail/1.4/mail-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/D:/Users/Dims/Design/!Lib/!m2/repository/javax/activation/activation/1.1/activation-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/D:/Users/Dims/Design/!Lib/!m2/repository/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty-management/6.1.26/jetty-management-6.1.26.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/D:/Users/Dims/Design/!Lib/!m2/repository/org/mortbay/jetty/jsp-2.1-jetty/6.1.26/jsp-2.1-jetty-6.1.26.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/D:/Users/Dims/Design/!Lib/!m2/repository/org/eclipse/jdt/core/3.1.1/core-3.1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/D:/Users/Dims/Design/!Lib/!m2/repository/org/mortbay/jetty/jsp-api-2.1-glassfish/2.1.v20091210/jsp-api-2.1-glassfish-2.1.v20091210.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/D:/Users/Dims/Design/!Lib/!m2/repository/org/mortbay/jetty/jsp-2.1-glassfish/2.1.v20091210/jsp-2.1-glassfish-2.1.v20091210.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/D:/Users/Dims/Design/!Lib/!m2/repository/org/eclipse/jdt/core/compiler/ecj/3.5.1/ecj-3.5.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[16] = file:/D:/Users/Dims/Design/!Lib/!m2/repository/ant/ant/1.6.5/ant-1.6.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[17] = file:/D:/Users/Dims/Design/!Lib/!m2/repository/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty-annotations/6.1.26/jetty-annotations-6.1.26.jar
[ERROR] urls[18] = file:/D:/Users/Dims/Design/!Lib/!m2/repository/org/apache/geronimo/specs/geronimo-annotation_1.0_spec/1.0/geronimo-annotation_1.0_spec-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[19] = file:/D:/Users/Dims/Design/!Lib/!m2/repository/org/mortbay/jetty/start/6.1.26/start-6.1.26.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------: org.mortbay.util.Attributes
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

Why all this?

Comment: I killed my local Maven repo, and could not reproduce this problem. However, maybe the issue is with the older Jetty plugin. I upgraded this example app: https://github.com/javalite/activeweb-bootstrap to the latest Jetty plugin, please try again.
Also, not sure if this is an issue, but your directory has an exclamation in a name: `D:\Users\Dims\Design\!Pure\activeweb-bootstrap`. Try placing your project in a directory without funny characters - maybe Maven is having an issue with a directory name.

Comment: this is my run of the project: https://gist.github.com/ipolevoy/b50352c3148d60e8af35