# Proper ActiveWeb configuration for simple app: server output is empty

Tags: java, web-applications, activeweb

I am fighting with ActiveWeb currently. I found, as it seems to me, that it's manual here http://javalite.io/activeweb contains a lot of desinformation.

First it says ActiveWeb is zer-configuration, which is not true. `web.xml` is still required. Also configuration in java is required. For example, file `AppBootstrap.java` should be present in appropriate location.

Second, I can't find it yet, how to configure views to work.

I have the following controller

```
package app.controllers;

import java.util.Date;

import org.javalite.activeweb.AppController;

public class GreetingController extends AppController {
    public void index() {

    }

    public void hello() {
        view("date", new Date().toString());
        view("name", param("name"));

    }
}
```

and it works as I see in debugger. When I open `http://localhost:8080/testapp/greeting/hello`, the breakpoint in `hello()` method is reached.

Unfortunately, the file `hello.ftl`, located in `WEB-INF/views/greeting/hello.ftl` is apparently ignored, because the browser output is empty.

Simultaneously, it is 100% empty, i.e. there are no HTTP headers at all. This points to suggestion, that some general config is missing.

Also, I have empty output on EVER query, including

`http://localhost:8080/testapp`

`http://localhost:8080/testapp/greeting`

`http://localhost:8080/testapp/abracadabra`

while some of the requests should return errors or service messages.

Request

`http://localhost:8080/`

returns `404` which means container is working normally.

My `web.xml` is follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>dispatcher</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.javalite.activeweb.RequestDispatcher</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>exclusions</param-name>
            <param-value>css,images,js</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>root_controller</param-name>
            <param-value>home</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>


    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>dispatcher</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**UPDATE**

When I removed `root_controller` parameter from `web.xml`, the server started to answer with directory listing on

`http://localhost:8080/testapp`

Other answers are still completely empty

**UPDATE 2**

Apparently `WEB-INF/views/layouts/default_layout.ftl` should be present. Otherwise the results will be empty and no error will be reported.

Answer (score 0):

something is definitely mis-configured in your app. Can you post sources somewhere on Github?
You can also clone this app: https://github.com/javalite/activeweb-bootstrap

Comment: Also, the page you are referring to is simply explanation of how the framework works. Please refer to this page: http://javalite.io/getting_started_activeweb as a Getting Started guide.

Comment: `activeweb-bootstrap` application just does not compile. try it yourself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25790336/a-required-class-was-missing-while-executing-org-mortbay-jettymaven-jetty-plugi

Comment: that was not a compilation problem, but rather some Maven issue I could not reproduce. Please, see my comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25790336/a-required-class-was-missing-while-executing-org-mortbay-jettymaven-jetty-plugi